# How to calculate upload speed with axios / javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have the following code for calculating the percentage completed for the file being uploaded:

```
const config = {
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: any) => {
    const percentCompleted = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total);
    this.props.setUploadPercentage(percentCompleted);
  }
};
```

And this works great, but I also need the speed at which the upload is happening and as I see it, `axios` doesn't provide such functionality out of the box. Is there any way with `JavaScript` to tell the speed between the user and the server in this situation?

Comment: You could calculate it based on the start time of the upload and the percentage uploaded.

Comment: `SPEED = (AMOUNT_COMPLETE)/(TIME_TAKEN)`

`AMOUNT_COMPLETE` can be in `kb, mb, gb` accordingly `SPEED` will be `kbps, mbps, gbps` assuming `TIME_TAKEN` is in seconds.